# Angularjs, events

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller

Контроллер moduleController подписывается на languageChanged, но при broadcast ничего не происходит. Прошу вашей помощи.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="translate">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.js"></script>
    <script src = "testAngular.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <select ng-model="selectedLanguage" ng-controller="translateController" ng-change = "changeLanguage()">
        <option ng-repeat="language in languages" value="{{language.value}}">{{language.text}}</option>
    </select>
    <div ng-model="text" ng-controller="moduleController" >
        {{text}}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

testAngular.js

```
var translateModel = {
    currentLanguage:"eng",
    languages:[
        {value:"eng", text:"english"},
        {value:"rus", text:"russian"}
    ]
};
var moduleData = {
    text:"",
};
var translate = angular.module("translate", []);
translate.controller("translateController", function ($scope){
    $scope.languages = translateModel.languages;
    $scope.currentLanguage = translateModel.currentLanguage;
    $scope.changeLanguage = function (){
        $scope.currentLanguage = $scope.selectedLanguage;
        alert("language "+$scope.currentLanguage +" was selected");
        $scope.$broadcast("languageChanged", $scope.currentLanguage );
    };
});
translate.controller("moduleController", function ($scope){
    $scope.text = moduleData.text;
    $scope.$on("languageChanged", function (event,currentLanguage){
        alert("requaire "+ currentLanguage + " text");
        if(currentLanguage == "rus"){
            $scope.text = "Текст на русском";
        };
        if(currentLanguage == "eng"){
            $scope.text = "Text on english";
        };
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

скопы данных контролеров находятся на одном уровне, поэтому просто одним вызовом `emit` или `broadcast` не обойтись, так как первый - шлет вверх по уровням, а второй - вниз.

Решить можно несколькими путями:

1. Слать из `rootScope`
2. поместить один из контроллеров внутрь другого
3. использовать для связи не события, а сервис

<sub>*небольшое отступление:* нет смысла писать `ng-model` на простом диве</sub>